# rnorm in For Loop Different n each iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to for loop to have normal distribution pulled 100 times, but with different n values that are given in a dataframe. I am using below mentioned code, but is giving me error. Is there a way to use different n for each iterations?

Many thanks,
Krina

```
> head(dat2_Placebo_n)
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

   Repl     N
  <int> <int>
1     1    78
2     2    71
3     3    60
4     4    66
5     5    71
6     6    82
> cv.tumor= 0.40
> sd.tumor<-sqrt(log((cv.tumor)^2+1))
> nRep <- 100
> result<-list()
> for(i in 1:nRep) {
+     n<- for(i in 1:dat2_Placebo_n$N) {n<-N[1:100,]}
+     Log_Tumor <- rnorm(n, log(6.8), sd.tumor)
+     Tumor <- exp(Log_Tumor)
+     result[[i]]<-Base_Tumor
+     }
Error: object 'N' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:dat2_Placebo_n$N :
  numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used
> result <- as.data.frame(unlist(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
cv.tumor<- 0.40
sd.tumor<-sqrt(log((cv.tumor)^2+1))
nRep <- 100
result_Placebo<-list()
for(i in 1:nRep) {
    ni<- dat2_Placebo_n$N[[i]]
    Log_Tumor <- rnorm(ni, log(6.8), sd.tumor)
    Tumor <- exp(Log_Tumor)
    result_Placebo[[i]]<-Tumor
    }
result_Placebo <- as.data.frame(unlist(result_Placebo))
```